# Jquery bind listeners to class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have a HTML document that got tags like:

```
<div class="sign"></div>
```

i want to replace those tags with canvas that represents a sign view
(user can touchmove and draw)
so i've binded listeners.

the problem is that only the first canvas has listeners and its possible to draw on.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('.sign').each(function () {


        var canvas = $("<canvas/>");
        canvas[0].width = 200;
        canvas[0].height = 100;
        canvas[0].setAttribute("style", "border:1px solid #000000");

        var ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');
        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';

        $(this).append(canvas);


        canvas.bind("touchstart", function () {

            ctx.moveTo(event.touches[0].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY);
        });

        canvas.bind("touchmove", function () {
            ctx.lineTo(event.touches[0].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY);
            ctx.stroke();
        });

        var br = $("<br/>");
        $(this).append(br);

        var btn = document.createElement('input');
        btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
        btn.setAttribute("value", "Clear");
        btn.setAttribute("onclick", "clearSignature()");

        $(this).append(btn);

    });

});
```

how can i bind those listeners to all canvases?

thanks.

Comment: I would bind all canvas outside after the each()

Comment: Agreed ... the problem of the inner .bind() is that you create closures, so `ctx` might not be what you expect.

Comment: declaring `var ctx = this.getContext('2d');` will solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `bind` inside the `each()` loop and I would simply attach the handlers after it (using event delegation), e.g.

```
$('body')
  .on("touchstart", 'canvas', function () {
    var ctx = this.getContext('2d');
    ctx.moveTo(event.touches[0].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY);
  })
  .on("touchmove", 'canvas', function () {
    var ctx = this.getContext('2d');
    ctx.lineTo(event.touches[0].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY);
    ctx.stroke();
  });
```

supposing that the context should be retrieved with `var ctx = this.getContext('2d');`

Comment: I've remove those bind out side the each loop and it still the same.. just the first canvas got listened.